Why I get an error when try to signing iOS app using Fastlane in Azure
Just now I'm trying to configure the CI/CD pipelines in Azure for our iOS App using Fastlane.
I have some config to build the app and get the all certificates using match. At this point everything work fine. I mean the all certificates are installed correctly and get the provisional profile mapping.
The problem I had it's when try to create the archive for the app in Azure. I get an error related to the profiles.
Error
error: No profiles for 'com.test.test' were found: Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'com.test.testv2'. Automatic signing is disabled and unable to generate a profile. To enable automatic signing, pass -allowProvisioningUpdates to xcodebuild. (in target 'testv2' from project 'test')

Important: the testv2 it's a target into my workspace.
Previously I crate the distribution certs/profiles using match correctly.
Here I left the lane I use to build and archive the app
desc "Build and archive"
  lane :build_archive_appstore do
    gym(
      scheme: scheme,
      output_directory: build_directory,
      clean: true,
      export_options: {
        provisioningProfiles: {
              "com.test.testv2": "match AppStore com.test.testv2"
            },
            allowProvisioningUpdates: true
      },
      include_symbols: include_symbols_in_build_artifact,
      archive_path: appstore_archive_path,
      output_name: appstore_ipa_name,
      configuration: appstore_build_configuration
    )
  end

When I run that lane locally (in my machine) run correctly without any error.
Any idea for that...
Thanks

Go inside xcode > runner > build settings > Provisioning profile
may be u can reset all OR set the profiles accordingly.

